# Check if .jar is opened by java

Tags: batch-file, jar

I want to create a program that checks whether the `.jar` file is opened by java itself, preferably in `.bat`. Apparently some people love to open it using `WinRAR` which is a bad option for me. I know how can I detect whether Java is installed or not by inputting this line:

```
java -version 2>NUL || GOTO:NotFound
```

Where, in `NotFound` function the program writes an error message and leaves. Now I'm stuck in how to see if `.jar` files are actually opened by java. Any ideas? maybe not in `.bat` maybe other language? though I'm pretty bad at the rest of them except for Java, Batch scripting and a little C.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do *you* have a jar file that you deploy and you don't want anybody to look inside? How does the presence or absence of java installation related?

Comment: @Vitaliy Basically I will create a temporary installer that will unpack my `.jar` file and my jar checker to a temporary folder, launch java checker to make sure that the system will open `.jar` file as intended and proceed opening my jar file. This will keep my `.jar` file form being opened by `WinRAR`, `7zip` etc.

Comment: @Vitaliy and the java presence is there to see whether the user needs to install java runtime or not.

Comment: It is still not clear. When you say 'open a jar file' do you mean 'unpack' or 'load into class path'? Why would anybody try to extract your jar and why does it bother you?

Comment: @Vitaliy I've managed to work it out. I will just put `javaw.exe` next to my `.jar` file and launch my jar using a bat file, with a command
`javaw.exe -jar apple.jar`. This will guarantee my result.